# Facebook Like Box - Posts by others not appearing

Tags: facebook, iframe, embed, feed

I am trying to implement the Facebook like box onto my website to show posts by others onto my Facebook page, however it is only showing a feed of the posts the page has made to its timeline and not the posts of other Facebook users.

I'm not sure how I can get this to happen? I'm not bothered about having the page's posts appear but I definitely want other's posts to appear in the feed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik the Plugin only shows posts "by the Page", so that is intentional. Think of it this way: If you get many User postings and only write a few Page postings, your Page postings would just not be very visible in the plugin.

You can only use the "force_checkin" parameter of the plugin to show checkins of friends, see Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages

---

If you want to get the posts of Users on a Page, you would have to use the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed

The docs include some example code for most relevant languages and you will get User posts too. Of course you have to design it on your own, you just get data from the API.

Comment: I see, what I'm wanting is to have a feed on my website of the posts others have written on my page, how would I go about it as I cannot see that there is a plugin for this?